# Powershell error provider BlinkStyle

Tags: windows, forms, powershell, errorprovider

I might be going crazy but I can't seem to figure out how to set the blinkrate on an ErrorProvider in Powershell.

Error provider is defined with:

```
$Global:ErrorProvider = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider
```

I've tried various different versions of:

```
$ErrorProvider.BlinkStyle() = [System.Windows.Forms.ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink]
```

or

```
$ErrorProvider.SetBlinkStyle([System.Windows.Forms.ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink])
```

With no success!

This is my first PS with some Windows forms elements so I'm still feeling my way through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify an enum value like this in PowerShell:

```
[System.Windows.Forms.ErrorBlinkStyle]::NeverBlink
```

It is essentially like accessing a static member of a type.  Try this:

```
$ErrorProvider.BlinkStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.ErrorBlinkStyle]::NeverBlink
```

Comment: Legend, exactly what I was looking for, I was sending myself crazy!

Comment: @mhouston100 in a script you definitely want to go with this, but if you're testing something interactively, you can also assign the underlying integer value and it'll automatically be cast to the correct enum: `$ErrorProvider.BlinkStyle = 2`